# Not getting action in UIbutton which is inside a Label of Custom Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have the following set-up: I have UITableView and i am setting custom cells in it called PBDetailsCell.

PBDetailsCell contains 2 labels: LeftLabel and RightLabel. I am setting a button inside the right label and when the button is pressed in the rightlabel of the PBDetailsCell, I would like for it to call the buttonPressed: method set up in the UITableView.

I am writing this code currently but it seems that the buttonPressed is not getting called...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{    PBDetailsCell *cell = (PBDetailsCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[PBDetailsCell reuseIdentifier]];
if(cell==nil){
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PBDetailsCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=_detailCell;
    _detailCell=nil;
}

    cell.leftLabel.text = @"  Action";

    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"action.png"];
    UIButton* but = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, cell.rightLabel.frame.size.width-20, cell.rightLabel.frame.size.height-10)];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [but setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.rightLabel addSubview:but];
} 
- (void)btnPressed:(id)sender
{ NSLog(@"Button pressed");}
```

Comment: Silly solution : adding cell.rightLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES; to the code will allow me to select the button..

Comment: Actually I think the silly solution is placing a UIButton in a UILabel. I can't think of a reason why this is needed.

Comment: Haha.. well its needed as per the app design.. i cant do anything about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

set `setUserInteractionEnabled` for both label and button to `yes`

Comment: Yes, the cell.rightLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES; did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

with

```
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Custom Cell then use the button static in UITableCell and add the button and label in xib and connect the method for button.

Comment: I want to do it programatically since i am also using the same custom cells for other rows in uitableview and i am using button in only one row...

Comment: [_detailCell.rightLabel addSubview:but]; try this also and check correctly.

Comment: wait I will check in demo project.

Answer (score 0):

The event must be `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` . Also try to make cell selection style to `None`. May be cell gets the touches.

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`